# Laravel giving a html form a unique url

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade I have field called `$jobs`.  I am trying give every single form a unique url based on the `$job->id`.  So the url is jobs/$job->id.  However when I click on the a tag for to submit the form all the urls show jobs/the last $job->id.  In my case all the urls show `job/386`.  What should I so every url has a unique url?  Here is my code.

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    <form method="post" action="{{url('jobs/'. $job->id)}}" id="start-jobs">
                  {{csrf_field()}}
       <a onclick="document.getElementById('start-jobs').submit()">( start )</a>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a JavaScript problem, not a Laravel problem.

All your forms have the same id (which isn't actually valid HTML), and which is why `getElementById('start-jobs')` is getting you the last one. If you need to have an identifier for all of the forms, use `class` instead of `id`.

It seems like you should be able to use just a regular submit button instead of the submit link you're using.

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    <form method="post" action="{{url('jobs/'. $job->id)}}" class="start-jobs">
                  {{csrf_field()}}
       <input type="submit" value="( start )">
    </form>
@endforeach
```